# Number of times a population proportion appears in a confidence interval

Tags: sas

I am trying to use SAS to compare a 95% Wald CI and a 95% CI based on exact calulations and calculate how many times a population proportion appears in either of the CI using 1000 samples of size 10 with a population proportion less than 15%.I started with 10 samples of size 10 with population proportion p=0.05. My code below seems to give the CI but I can not get it to count how many times the proportion appears in the CI. Any help? And how do I get SAS to do 1000 samples of size 10?

```
%let numsampled=10;
data bin_sample(keep=bin);
 call streaminit(4321);  *initialize the seed;
 do id = 1 to &numsampled;
     bin = rand('Binomial',0.05,10);    
     output;
 end;
run;
proc print data=bin_sample;
run;
proc freq data=Bin_sample order=freq;
   tables bin / binomial(wald exact) alpha=.05;
/*   weight Count;*/
   title 'Two Confidence Intervals for binomial trials';
run;
```

Comment: Well, if you're looking to increase to 1000 samples of size 10, just change the `%let numsampled` to 1000.  `bin = rand('Binomial',0.05,10)` already specifies 10 trials.

Comment: @Stu. Thanks. Does the code above also count how many times the proportion p=0.05 (or any other value less than 15%) appear in the CI?